# How to Set permission to view folder in OSX App?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, utility

I coded for osx application to view file from path but I had received error as

> The file “Backup” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission
>   to view it.

So I want to set access permission code to view that list of files. If any one have idea or solution please help me. The code as pasted below for reference:

```
let path = "~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/"
    let backupDirectory = NSString(string: path).expandingTildeInPath
    do
    {
        let subBackupPaths = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: backupDirectory)
        for path in subBackupPaths
        {
    //operations
    }
    } catch let error {
     print(error) 
}
```

- When i run code this error i am facing error. it is throwing from 'subBackupPaths' to exceptions.
- This is working in High Sierra.
- This is not working in Mojave.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Backup” couldn’t
>   be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder ), NSURL=file:///Users/rohan/Library/Application%20Support/MobileSync/Backup,
>   NSFilePath=/Users/rohan/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c6dda0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

Comment: Mojave introduced new security measures to prevent Apps from accessing certain directories. Look up the corresponding WWDC 2018 videos, e.g. [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/702/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant access for privacy protected directories in "Security & Privacy" to your application before you can access MobileSync/Backup.

Go to (Apple) -> Settings -> Security and open the "Privacy" tab.

Now it should work.

[image]